# Not able to get addIssueWithName: work in NKLibrary

Tags: ios, xcode, newsstand-kit

I am trying to work with NKLibrary but I having trouble getting addIssueWithName to work properly.

Here I am adding my issues:

```
 NSString *name = tmpIssue.name;

    NKLibrary *nkLib = [NKLibrary sharedLibrary];

    NKIssue *nkIssue = [nkLib issueWithName:name];

    NSLog(@"issue name %@",nkIssue.name);

    if(!nkIssue) {
        NSLog(@"Added issue with name: %@ and date: %@",[tmpIssue.name copy],[jsonDict2 objectForKey:@"Date"]);

        nkIssue = [nkLib addIssueWithName:[tmpIssue.name copy] date:[jsonDict2 objectForKey:@"Date"]];

    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"No need to add issue with name %@. It's already exists.",tmpIssue.name);

    }
```

and then I am trying to check if the issue is added using this code:

```
 NKLibrary *nkLib = [NKLibrary sharedLibrary];
NKIssue *nkIssue = [nkLib issueWithName:issue.name];

if(nkIssue==nil){

    NSLog(@"issue is nil");

}
```

The problem is that the issues are not added and I am always getting "nil". Even without closing the app.
Any ideas what is the problem?

Comment: What's your info plist setup like?  Have you added the `UINewsstandApp` key?

Comment: Please post it as answer. It solved my problem. I didn't want the app in the newsstand so that's why I didn't change the plist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've got a `YES` for your app's `UINewsstandApp` info plist key.

From what I understand, NewsstandKit is deeply tied to other system-exclusive resources, so it makes sense to me that, if your setup isn't 100% complete compared to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/NewsstandKit_Framework/_index.html), that you won't see the functionality you're trying to build.